# Who sees Twitter messages starting with @?

Tags: twitter, twitter-direct-message

When I do a tweet starting by `@AnotherUser` like this:

```
@AnotherUser Hello I would like to tell you that ...
```

**will the tweet appear in the timeline of my followers?**

If so, it would be annoying because the goal is to do a "Direct message" to someone. (Why don't I do a Direct message? Because you cannot do a direct message to someone who doesn't follow you.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will the tweet appear in the timeline of my followers?

Assuming it's a new tweet, your followers and the followers of the person you're mentioning will see it.

If it's an actual reply, only those people who follow you *and* that person you're replying to will see it.

A note: You *can* direct message someone who doesn't follow you if they've turned on the "Anyone Can send messages" feature.

---

Sources:

- [Here's how Twitter @mentions are changing](http://mashable.com/2016/05/24/twitter-mentions-explained/)
- [Twitter Is Finally Putting an End to Tweets That Start with “.@”](https://socialmediaweek.org/blog/2016/06/twitter-finally-putting-end-tweets-start/)
- [Twitter blog: Coming soon: express even more in 140 characters](https://blog.twitter.com/official/en_us/a/express-even-more-in-140-characters.html)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. Do you have a source about 1st and 2nd sentences? (maybe a link can be useful for future ref).

Comment: _the followers of the person you're mentioning will see it_, this is confusing me, I guess if the mentioned person do not retweet or quote the tweet his/her followers will not see it. If he/she reply on the tweet it will only seen in _tweets & replies_ section until he/she self retweet.

Comment: @serenesat: It is confusing, especially since they just changed the criteria for who sees what just last year. That's why you _used to_ see `.@username` replies, so that the tweet would be visible to more people.